# Why are we using water pipe instead of air pipe to warm our houses?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

In France, most of the houses are using water pipes. I wonder why this choice was originally done.

Comment: My house uses an air pipe. Or rather, air ducts that feed warm air from the furnace to the rest of the house

Comment: Why not?  What do you really want to know?

Comment: I think this question is moot. We don't use only water pipes. Water pipes is actually an older design. Today we use many differing methods; water pipes, air ducts from a furnace, solar heating, electric elements, wood or gas fireplaces. Some houses have no heating at all.

Comment: In France, most of the houses are using water pipes. I wonder why this choice was originally done, that's all ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all boils down to energy  and [heat capacity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity)

> [Water has a specific heat](http://www2.vims.edu/bridge/DATA.cfm?Bridge_Location=archive0909.html) of 4.186 J/g degreesC, versus air, which has a specific heat of 1.005 J/g degreesC.

To keep a radiator at a temperature designed to heat a room, 70C or more, it would take a multiple amount of air blown through, as not only the specific heat per gram but also the density of air is much smaller than the density of water. Much larger pipes would have to be designed.

Air is good for convective heating, i.e. displacing the air in the room with hot air, from ducts large enough to be able to transfer the energy needed to heat a room.